# How to loop through all the pixels of an image?

Tags: php, gd

I want to loop through all the pixels of an image, find the rgba value of that pixel, and do something with those pixels.

### Example

Say I have an image that's 100x100 pixels.  I want to find the value of each one of those pixels with the function I already made:

```
function getPixel($image, $x, $y) {

  $colors = imagecolorsforindex($image, imagecolorat($image, $x, $y));
  $inrgba = 'rgba(' . $colors['red'] . ',' . $colors['green'] . ',' . $colors['blue'] . ',' . $colors['alpha'] . ')';
  return $inrgba;
}
```

And store those values, along with the dimensions of the image, in an array, or an array of arrays.  I want to use the end result in a html page.

How do I do this?

Comment: is php the best option for this?

Comment: Have you looked at the php manual at the image functions. Php might not be the fastest solution for this sort of thing, especially on large images, but it is more then capable of doing this.

Comment: gd pixel operations are pretty slow...

Comment: @Dagon Why does it matter? Sometimes we have to use the tools at hand which aren't necessarily the best option.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde and sometimes people say they want to language X because that's all they know, or, have not considered alternatives. Also known as the  *law of the instrument*

Comment: @Dagon Very true! Which was thinking was probably the spirit you asked it in, but thought I would defend the OP anyway. :-)

Comment: ok, but maybe not bother with answered questions over a year old ;-)

Comment: which will be the best option for doing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
for($x=1;$x<=$width;$x++)
{
    for($y=1;$y<=$height;$y++)
    {
        $pixel=getPixel($image, $x, $y);
        //do something
    }
}
```

What this will do is find each pixel in each column.

```
i=iteration
pixel coordinate = (x,y)
```

For a 5 x 5 image the iteration would look like this:

```
i1 = (1,1)
i2 = (1,2)
i3 = (1,3)
i4 = (1,4)
i5 = (1,5)
i6 = (2,1)
i7 = (2,2)
i8 = (2,3)
i9 = (2,4)
i10 = (2,5)
i11 = (3,1)
i12 = (3,2)
i13 = (3,3)
i14 = (3,4)
i15 = (3,5)
i16 = (4,1)
i17 = (4,2)
i18 = (4,3)
i19 = (4,4)
i20 = (4,5)
i21 = (5,1)
i22 = (5,2)
i23 = (5,3)
i24 = (5,4)
i25 = (5,5)
```

Comment: It is not a function so it does not return anything. But on each iteration it places the x coordinate in the `$x` variable and a `y` coordinate in the `$y` variable.

Comment: Bounds is starting from: 0 $x< [...] $y<

Answer (score 4):

Here's the complete answer, without the out of bounce error

```
<?php

    $src    = '2fuse.jpg';
    $im     = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $size   = getimagesize($src);
    $width  = $size[0];
    $height = $size[1];

    for($x=0;$x<$width;$x++)
    {
        for($y=0;$y<$height;$y++)
        {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
            var_dump($r, $g, $b);
        }
    }
```