# How can I point to each pixel within an image without using for loops?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to go pixel by pixel in my php code to do perform some math calculations on each of the pixels. However, using for loops to do so is taking a long time to complete.

For example, I need to do something like this just to determine what the color is at every pixel:

```
for ($x =0; $x <$imagewidth; $x++){
    for($y = 0; $y <$imageheight; $y++){
        //determine color of each pixel from image
        $newpixelcolor =imagecolorat($smoothimage,$x,$y); }}
```

Please let me know if there is an easier way to move through the array in php... I don't think the implode function would work in this case... but let me know if I'm wrong and thanks.

Comment: There is no easier way than this, even in [2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593638/how-to-loop-through-all-the-pixels-of-an-image) your current code is the only known method.

Comment: ps, pre-increment is faster than post-increment by a small margin, and with image manipulation, there can be so many iterations that they can become significant